# Upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 (Package Conflicts)

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, upgrade, package-management

I'm running 10.10 and have stayed within the repositories. When it is time to upgrade to 11.04 are there any "programs" in the 10.10 repository that are a potential conflict with 11.04 and should remove before "Upgrading?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update manager handles this for you, you shouldn't have to do anything.

Where it becomes problematic is when people start adding third party applications. The upgrader does it's best to cope by disabling PPAs on upgrades, etc. but you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

The update manager (`sudo update-manager -c -d`) will handle all conflict for you. And will ask you if you want to delete unecessary package.

To maximise your chance to go fine, please use (`sudo aptitute install -f`) to ensure that there is no conflict BEFORE your update. It's quite importante.

All PPAs will be desactivate for the upgrade. You can reactivate them after by editing the sources.list file or by the GUI. It's better to not reactivate them before the official relase of Natty.

Comment: Probably best on upgrades to use apt-get or update-manager, as aptitude is not as well tested in these cases: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/592336/comments/19